# How to get all implementors/subclasses of an interface with Guice?

Tags: java, guice

With Spring, you can define an array property and have Spring inject one of every (@Component) class that derives from the given type.

Is there an equivalent for this in Guice? Or an extension point to add this behavior?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This looks like a use case for Guice [MultiBinder](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings). You could have something like that:

```
interface YourInterface {
    ...
}

class A implements YourInterface {
    ...
}

class B implements YourInterface {
    ...
}

class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override protected void configure() {
        Multibinder.newSetBinder(YourInterface.class).addBinding().to(A.class):
        Multibinder.newSetBinder(YourInterface.class).addBinding().to(B.class):
    }
}
```

And you can inject a `Set<YourInterface>` anywhere:

```
class SomeClass {
    @Inject public SomeClass(Set<YourInterface> allImplementations) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That should match with what you need.

Comment: It does indeed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You'll find Multibindings in a separate jar ("guice extension"): http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.inject.extensions%22%20AND%20a%3A%22guice-multibindings%22

Comment: May i ask how do we do this in spring?

Answer (score 16):

[Guice Multibindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings) require you to explicitly addBinding() for `A` & `B` to `YourInterface`.  If you would like a more "transparent" (automatic) solution such as what AFAIK Spring offers out-of-the-box, then assuming that Guice already knows about `A` & `B` because you already have a binding for `A` & `B` elsewhere anyway, even if not explicit but just implicit e.g. through an `@Inject` somewhere else, then and only then you alternatively could use something like this for auto-discovery ([inspired by as done here](https://git.opendaylight.org/gerrit/#/c/48077/7/mdsalutil/mdsalutil-testutils/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/genius/datastoreutils/testutils/TestableDataTreeChangeListenerModule.java), based on [accessing Guice injector in a Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989991/accessing-guice-injector-in-its-module)):

```
class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
   @Override protected void configure() { }

   @Provides
   @Singleton
   SomeClass getSomeClass(Injector injector) {
       Set<YourInterface> allYourInterfaces = new HashSet<>();
       for (Key<?> key : injector.getAllBindings().keySet()) {
           if (YourInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(key.getTypeLiteral().getRawType())) {
            YourInterface yourInterface = (YourInterface) injector.getInstance(key);
            allYourInterfaces.add(yourInterface);
       }
       return new SomeClass(allYourInterfaces);
   }
}
```

Note again that this approach does NOT require any classpath scanning; it just looks at all already known bindings in the Injector for anything that IS-A `YourInterface`.

Comment: I am trying same. But It is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705146/get-all-the-instance-subclass-of-trait-using-google-guice

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

```
Class SomeModule : AbstractModule() {
        
            override fun configure() {
                val myBinder: Multibinder<MyInterface> = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), MyInterface::class.java)
                myBinder.addBinding().to(Implementation1::class.java)
                 myBinder.addBinding().to(Implementation2::class.java)
}
```

**Usage**

```
@Inject constructor(private val someVar:Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards MyInterface>)
```