# Guice : Is it possible to get all binded instances given a particular parent/interface/annotation?

Tags: guice, guice-servlet

I know this may not be dependency injection in its purest form, but let's say I have to use :

```
@Inject
Injector injector;
```

With this injector, is it possible to get *all* the binded instances given :

1. A parent class each instances would inherited from?
2. An interface each instances would implement?
3. An annotation each instances would have?

I see the *Injector#findBindingsByType()* method but I'm not sure if it can help in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a list of a given type associated through multibindings.  Check out the docs:

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085200/how-to-get-all-implementors-subclasses-of-an-interface-with-guice/40558788#40558788 describes a way to "auto-discover" instances by implemented interface as a more dynamic alternative to explicit multi bindings.