# How to move an anonymous Provider that references fields in the module into a separate class?

Tags: java, guice, inner-classes

Toy example:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  private static final Foo foo;

  public MyModule(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    bind(Bar.class).toProvider(new Provider<Bar>() {
      @Override public Bar get() {
        return foo.getBar();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This lets me lazily invoke the `.getBar()` method of a user-provided `Foo` instance stored in a field of `MyModule`. However now the [provider has its own dependencies](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProviderBindings) - hence I need to define a non-anonymous class I specify an `@Inject` constructor on. Something like:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  private static final Foo foo;

  public MyModule(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    bind(Bar.class).toProvider(BarProvider.class);
  }

  BarProvider implements Provider<Bar> {
    private Baz baz;

    @Inject BarProvider(Baz baz) {
      this.baz = baz;
    }

    @Override public Bar get() {
      return foo.getBar(baz);
    }
  }
}
```

Perfect! Except [Guice doesn't like this](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how-can-i-inject-an-inner-class)...

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Injecting into inner classes is not supported.  Please use a 'static' class (top-level or nested) instead of com.example.MyModule$BarProvider.

So, I'm in a bind. I need to access both a field on the module and an injected type from a `Provider` class at the same time. Is there any way to do this?

---

**Note:** this toy example excludes some of the actual complexity - in particular the `bind()` statement is more involved, which is why I can't simply define an `@Provides` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize I was getting hung up on having Guice construct my `Provider` for me, which I don't actually need to do. Despite the example in Guice's documentation passing in a `DatabaseTransactionLogProvider.class` a better parallel to the first snippet would be to construct an instance of my `Provider` manually, and pass in both the `Foo` instance and a `Provider<Baz>` instance ([provided by the module](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#getProvider-java.lang.Class-)).

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  private static final Foo foo;

  public MyModule(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  @Override
  public void configure() {
    bind(Bar.class).toProvider(new BarProvider(foo, getProvider(Baz.class));
  }

  static BarProvider implements Provider<Bar> {
    private final Foo foo;
    private final Provider<Baz> bazProvider;

    BarProvider(Foo foo, Provider<Baz> bazProvider) {
      this.foo = foo;
      this.bazProvider = bazProvider;
    }

    @Override public Bar get() {
      return foo.getBar(bazProvider.get());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In part, injecting into an inner class is impossible because Guice can't reflectively create an inner instance without an outer parent instance (the equivalent of the arcane [`outerInstance.new InnerInstance()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4070777/1426891) syntax).

Some options:

- Make Foo injectable through your graph, possibly hidden in a [PrivateModule](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) so it's not exposed to your entire graph (if that's important to you).
- Use an anonymous inner Provider (or an extracted equivalent), and get a `Provider<Baz>` from AbstractModule's [`getProvider(Class<T>)`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#getProvider-java.lang.Class-) method. You'll get an exception if you try to call that before the Injector is created, but for creating a Provider the way you're doing, that's probably not a problem.
- Post your `bind` outside of a toy problem, to see whether `@Provides` is possible with some cleverness.

Related: [Accessing Guice injector in its Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15989991/1426891)

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I realized after posting that what I needed was `getProvider()`. It was staring me right in the face, but for some reason it didn't click :)