# Guice injection in a child class of a AbstractModule class

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, guice

This is regarding to the `Play framework 2.5.x`

I have few Guice modules which extended by the `AbstractModule` and they are added as bindings to the `GuiceApplicationBuilder` method like below.

```
@Override
public GuiceApplicationBuilder builder(ApplicationLoader.Context context) {
    return initialBuilder
            .in(context.environment())
            .bindings(new LoggerModule())
            .bindings(new BaseConnectionModule(configuration))
            .bindings(new CacheModule(configuration))
            .bindings(new DaoModule())
            ....
```

One of my module (say `CacheModule`) declared private variables in that which are also Guice injected to be used in that class(inside `Guice @Provides` methods). The bindings for those variable are done in one of a GuiceModule (say `BaseConnectionModule`) which bound prior to the current module as mentioned in above code.

My question is, when the application get started, such variables declared as private in the `CacheModule` are not get instantiated.

Can someone please answer to this?

Comment: Can you show relevant code from `CacheModule`?

Comment: Did you mean injected private variables or method (with @Provides) where used them?

Comment: [As I wrote here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15989991/1426891), there are very limited ways that you can access injected values from within a Guice module. It is very atypical to use @Inject fields in a Module, unless you are getting a Guice Module from a different injector. I will second Ketan above that it is important for us to see CacheModule so we can give you more specific advice or alternatives.