# What happens if you pass an Injector as argument in a @Provides method

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have seen several usage in a project I am working as the following (I am posting the essence of the code so it is easier to read):

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    i.getInstance(Foo.class);
}

class Foo {}

class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Provides
    public Foo getFoo(Injector injector) {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

When I tried to print the `injector.toString()` in the module I think Guice somehow bound the Injector to the instance `i` itself.

Like for example

```
public static void main(Strings[] args) {
    Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    Injector j = i.getInstance(Injector.class);
    if (i == j) {
        // true
    }
}
....
```

So in this case can someone please shed some light on how Guice obtains the instance of Injector in the `getFoo(injector)` method? Thanks!

Comment: I think I found in the Guice API doc that each Injector contains a default binding of itself...

https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html

So this explained why injector will return itself if trying to get an instance of Injector...Still I would appreciate it very much if anyone can kindly explain the internal mechanism of this.

Answer (score 1):

Injector is injectable in your graph, and Guice will supply arguments to `@Provides` methods. However, you should only ever need to inject your Injector in very rare cases, and there is no need to request an Injector if you don't use it.

---

```
@Provides
public Foo getFoo(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2) {
    return new Foo(dep1, dep2);
}
```

This assumes Guice can create instances of Dep1 and Dep2 (via constructors, bindings, or `@Provides` methods), and is roughly equivalent to if you had annotated a constructor in Foo. Guice will inject instances of Dep1 and Dep2 when calling the Foo constructor, and Guice will provide the instances when calling your `@Provides Foo getFoo` method above.

```
@Inject public Foo(Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2) { /* ... */ }
```

As in the documentation for the Injector class that you linked ([latest docs available here](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html)):

> Contains several default bindings:
>
> - This `Injector` instance itself
> - A `Provider<T>` for each binding of type `T`
> - The `Logger` for the class being injected
> - The `Stage` in which the Injector was created

Consequently, you may put Dep1, Dep2, Provider, Provider, Injector, or `Provider<Injector>` into your `@Provides` method arguments or `@Inject` constructor arguments (or `@Inject` fields, etc). Internally, Injector support happens in [`InjectorShell.java`](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/master/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/InjectorShell.java#L218) as a special case, because parent and child Injectors will return different instances of Injector as an exception to Guice's rules about parents and children with the same bindings.

---

**Why would you want to inject an Injector?** For the sake of reading and testing, it is usually better to inject the dependency you need (e.g. Dep1) or its provider (e.g. `Provider<Dep1>`). You would only need to inject the Injector if you need to pass it into some other object, like a legacy Service Locator that you've adapted to use your Guice Injector, or if you need to use the Injector reflectively [via Guice's SPI](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ExtendingGuice) or [to get an instance based on a Class object](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#getInstance-java.lang.Class-). These are rare, and not likely to be necessary in most of your classes or `@Provides` methods.

```
/** Exceptions, generics, and casting omitted for readability. */
@Provides SomeInterface getSomeInterface(
    MyAppPreferences preferences,
    Injector injector) {
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(preferences.getSomeInterfaceImplName());
  return injector.getInstance(clazz);
}
```

---

See also: [Accessing Guice injector in its Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15989991/1426891)

Comment: Thank you very much, those are very helpful :)