# guice injection without injector

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Below is my module class

```
public class ABCModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new JpaPersistModule(Configuration.get("error-persister")));
        bind(DBService.class).to(DBServiceImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
        bind(DBRepository.class).to(DBRepositoryImpl.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }

    @ProvidesIntoOptional(ProvidesIntoOptional.Type.ACTUAL)
    public ErrorHandler getErrorHandler() {
        return new ABCHandler();
    }
}
```

and ABCHandler has

```
private final DBService dbService;

@Inject
public ABCHandler() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ABCModule());
    injector.getInstance(PersistenceInitializer.class);
    this.dbService = injector.getInstance(DBService.class);
}

@Override
public void handle() {
    dbService.store("abc");
}
```

`ABCModule` instance gets created and gets passed to some generic module. As you can see `ABCModule` provides `ABCHandler` and `ABCHandler` again uses `ABCModule` to create injector and service instance. It works but I know it is not correct. `Module` is called twice. How do I inject `dbService` inside `ABCHandler` without having to use injector or creating module instance. I don't want to create a dummy empty module just to creates instances. can you please suggest. If I just use `@Inject` on `dbService` without using injector, it comes as null. I am using `Provider` inside `Module`, can something similar done for `dbService`. Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbService` is already injectable and you can pass it in `getErrorHandler` method

```
  @ProvidesIntoOptional(ProvidesIntoOptional.Type.ACTUAL)
  public ErrorHandler getErrorHandler(DBService dbService) {
    return new ABCHandler(dbService);
  }
```

In this case `ABCHandler` constructor can be changed to this

```
  @Inject
  public ABCHandler(DBService dbService) {
    this.dbService = dbService;
  }
```

More details you can find here
[Accessing Guice injector in its Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989991/accessing-guice-injector-in-its-module)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was quite helpful.